# Subject of investigation vs. Object of investigation?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage

which of the following is better:

1. "He is the *subject* of our current investigation."
2. "He is the *object* of our current investigation."

Comment: What do you want to mean? Betterness can only be judged if we know what you're trying to say.

Comment: These are two possibilities of literal sentences. E.g. assume John is suspect of stealing a pen in the company. Then someone can either say "He is the subject of our current investigation." or "He is the object of our current investigation." Which one is better?